# KQL Get Used Capacity on Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, kql

is there a way to query all storage accounts in subscriptions called "storage" and get the used capacity for each one. I'm trying to create an alert rule if they exceed 1024 gb capacity, but I'm not seeing used capacity anywhere. You can go into each storage account and configure the alert within the storage account, but that's not practical.

I can get some information from storage account using, this for availability:

```
AzureMetrics 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.STORAGE"
| where _ResourceId contains "storage"
| where MetricName =~ "availability"
| project TimeGenerated, ResourceGroup, _SubscriptionId, Resource, MetricName, Average, UnitName
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UsedCapacity**

[Exporting platform metrics to other locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#exporting-platform-metrics-to-other-locations)

> Using diagnostic settings is the easiest way to route the metrics, but
> there are some limitations:
> Exportability. All metrics are exportable
> through the REST API, but some can't be exported through diagnostic

[Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftstoragestorageaccounts)

| Metric | Exportable via Diagnostic Settings? | Metric Display Name | Unit | Aggregation Type | Description | Dimensions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UsedCapacity | Yes | Used capacity | Bytes | Average | The amount of storage used by the storage account. For standard storage accounts, it's the sum of capacity used by blob, table, file, and queue. For premium storage accounts and Blob storage accounts, it is the same as BlobCapacity or FileCapacity. | No Dimensions |

```
AzureMetrics
|   where ResourceProvider  == "MICROSOFT.STORAGE"
|   where MetricName        == "UsedCapacity"
|   where SubscriptionId    == "ebb79bc0-aa86-44a7-8111-cabbe0c43993"
|   summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, ResourceGroup, Resource, Average) by _ResourceId
```

[image: QueryResults]

[Fiddle](https://ms.portal.azure.com#@72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/blade/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring_Logs/DemoLogsBlade/resourceId/%2FDemo/source/LogsBlade.AnalyticsShareLinkToQuery/q/H4sIAAAAAAAAA02PT2vCQBTE736Kh6cWjBgM1Rw8BGlDDjYliWd5uzvoHtaEt1lbpR%252B%252BFf%252FObYbfDEx2CoIVerHaD36J6HsHAVXwbRCNL2kP1kCIFgsaroplVdblRzOum7LK8vfhU%252BUy8skOdNW5svYwS%252B5Y2%252F74TNdBeS226227L8yNhlKzVOlJxDx%252Fi5KEZ9E8juNIs1KY6GSaptPLig%252FOsdgTiGW7cfzz0liHHHsI9zCj%252B4Nc2tA97Iiywz%252ByxSupI21ucWH%252BAN%252BhpUgJAQAA/timespan/P1D)

Comment: Hi David, can we improvise the query to create alert when used capacity exceeds 80% or so...the above query just list out the used capacity..thanks in advance

Comment: Please post a new question

Comment: Hi David, here is the link for new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75681807/kql-queries-to-get-total-storage-account-used-space-in-percentage
thanks