# Azure Monitoring: How to create dashboard that show amount of storage left in a storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-application-insights, azure-dashboard

How to create a dashboard that shows the amount of storage left in a storage account?
I don't want to create alerts but I want to create a tile in the dashboard that either show one of the following:

1. the amount of storage used by the storage account against its quota, hence some sort of percentage
2. The amount of remaining storage space
3. The amount of remaining storage space as a percentage

Comment: Are you trying to create through portal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Norrin Rad.
By referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72917533/kql-get-used-capacity-on-storage-account), I have written a query for storage availability below:

```
    AzureMetrics 
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(timespan) //(eg:24 hrs)
    | where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.STORAGE"
    | where _ResourceId contains "storage"
    | where MetricName =~ "availability"
    | project
        TimeGenerated,
        ResourceGroup,
        SubscriptionID,
        Resource, //(Here it is storage account)
        MetricName,
        Average,
        UnitName
```

Go to Azure portal and follow these steps:

```
Monitor->Logs->Write a query->save it
```

After running the query, you will be able to see the logs as shown below:
[image]

After successfully executing the query, You will be able to pin it to your dashboards.

[image]
[image]

**Note**: While saving the query make sure that you need to save content to azure storage account also by assigning user managed identity with the role "Storage Blob data contributor" (Eg: Blob storage)

[Reference link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftstoragestorageaccounts)