# KQL queries to get total storage account used space in percentage

Tags: azure-keyvault, kql, azure-monitor

I am writing KQL queries to setup alerting mechanism in our environment. However we got blocked for few alerts.

I need to get total used capacity of storage account in percentage, with below query I am able to get total used Capacity but not in percentage:

```
     AzureMetrics
     |   where ResourceProvider  == "MICROSOFT.STORAGE"
     |   where MetricName        == "UsedCapacity"
```

Comment: Removed second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and below is the result**

> need to get total used capacity of storage account in percentage, with
> below query i am able to get total used Capacity but not in percentage

You can use below **KQL** query to get the output in percentage.

```
AzureMetrics  
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.STORAGE"  
| summarize Totalvalue = sum(Total) by MetricName| as T  
| extend Percentage = round(100.0 * Totalvaule / toscalar(T | summarize sum(Totalvalue)), 2)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: thanks Venkat but i would like put condition in the query like 
| where UsedCapacity > 80%

Comment: i hope this works 
| where MetricName contains "UsedCapacity" and Percentage >= 80  right ?

Comment: AzureMetrics | where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.STORAGE" | summarize Totalvalue = sum(Total) by MetricName| as T | extend Percentage = round(100.0 * Totalvalue / toscalar(T | summarize sum(Totalvalue)), 2) | where Percentage >= 20 You can use above query if you need output with Percentage: https://i.imgur.com/z7umNSI.png